# Material 3 Icon to represent Manual mode?

Tags: icon, google-material-design

I'm looking for an icon to represent the camera manual mode. Typically, it's represented by an M in a circle but I haven't found it in the Material 3 Icons set.

Does the M in a circle exist in the Material 3 icon set? If not, is there an alternative icon in the set that would represent it?